# Неправильное отображение в блоке div через jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добрый день всем.
Попросили посмотреть код, в котором есть одна проблема. в jQuery я не особо.
Есть сайт, на нём выполняешь задания, за задания даются баллы. Есть два дива с одинаковым классом .balance_num, в котором отображаются баллы, после выполнения к этим баллам прибавляется некое количество и вот общая сумма в итога отображается неверно.

```
_balance: funtion(n) {
  var points_a = $('.balance_num').text() * 1 //берется изначальное количество баллов
  var points_plus = points_a + (n * 1); //прибавляется баллы за задание
  $('.balance_num').text(points_plus); //вставляется обратно в оба div
}
```

Вроде всё просто. Но например если было 12 баллов, за задание прибавили 3 балла, и вместо 15 баллов он почему то вставляет число 1215.

Подскажите куда копать?

Comment: $('.balance_num') это массив, может стоит выбирать eq(0)?

Comment: в конце .text(point_plus) пропущена буква s - points_plus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том что у вас дублируются классы у блоков. Вам для расчетов нужно взять значение только одного блока. Да и умножать на 1 нет смысла.

```js
_balance: funtion(n) {
  var points_a = parseInt($('.balance_num:first').text()); // приводим строку к числу, и берем значение с первого div'a
  var points_plus = points_a + (n); 
  $('.balance_num').text(points_plus); 
}
```

Comment: Да, спасибо, и вправду, позже я тоже подумал что нужно выбирать первый блок. 
`и в третей строке нужно (n * 1)`

Answer (score -1):

```
_balance: function(n) {
  // Так как элементов с классом balance_num несколько, то нам нужно собрать их в массив для последующей обработки в цикле
  let divs = $('.balance_num');
  // проходим в цикле по всем элементам с классом balance_num
  $.each(divs, function(i, div){
    // Получаем содержащийся в элементе текст и приводим его к числу
    let points_a = parseInt($(div).text());
    // Прибавляем нужное число, переданное в функцию аргументом
    let points_plus = parseInt(points_a + n);
    // Обновляем содержимое элемента
    $(div).text(points_plus);  
  });
}
```

Comment: Он всё равно вставляет в оба diva 1215 вместо 15.

Comment: parse он заменил умножением на единицу. `'' + points_plus` - это бредок.

Comment: Исправил ответ ))

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.